# Java help me Login with txt File

Tags: java, authentication

I do not understand why I always get the result is false !
I tried sysout both *input* and *split []*. They are all the same
 ,Also I can not use **this.dispose ()**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String record = null;
            FileReader in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileReader("login.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

                String username = txtUser.getText();
                String pass = txtPass.getText();
                while ((record = br.readLine()) !=null) {

                    String[] split = record.split(",");

                    if (username.equals(split[0]) && pass.equals(split[1])) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU IS LOG IN",
                                  "OK", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    }
                    else {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ACCOUNT OR PASSWORD IS NOT ACCURATE",
                                  "False", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }


                    // Delete else branch
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getCause();
            }
        }
    });
```

it is login.txt

```
user,pass
Taka,123
```

and ***txtpass*** is a textfiel normal

Comment: could you please post the contents of `login.txt` as it is hard to guess?

Comment: As long we do not know about the``login.txt`` and where the magic `txtPass` variable comes from, your question will be impossible to answer, don't you think?

Comment: thanks for the reminder, i have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going out on a limb here as I cannot comment yet, but it might have to do with your inclusion of *user,pass* in the login.txt file. Try to remove that line so the file starts with the actual user and password.

Also, I'm not sure about the use of this code, but storing passwords in a plaintext file is never a good idea.